# what is the right way to check that an object is not null in react before assigning one of its properties to a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

In React it is very commong that as components get updated objects go from null to their intended content. This is a dynamic process that can create errors everytime you assing a property from those objects to another variable.

Lets say that user is the object that will go from null to the actual user object and that I want to extract the property uid from user:

```
const uid = user.uid
```

This can trigger a fatal error in react if user is null when I try to execute this operation.

I have tried to use:

`user && const uid = user.uid`, but it doesn't work at all.

Would the right way to do this be:

```
const uid = user && user.uid
```

any comments/ sugestions?

Comment: `const uid = user?.uid` might be what you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined**

So do this

```js
const uid = user?.uid // will be undefined if not there else the actually value
```

Comment: it doesn't work when the object is an array of objects, for instance if I want to preempt an fatal error in react before my array is not undefined, I can't use array?[0]?.property1, so I am using array && array[0[?.property1. Is that the elegant way?

Comment: I don't know but thats a good question ask it

Comment: You can do this though to catch an `undefined` array. `const uid = array?undefined:array[0].uid`