# What is the correct way to prevent an error in React when an array of objects is still undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It's common in React that an element is rendered before all its variables are defined, with final rendering being correct. To prevent fatal errors we usually use the ? operator as suggested in the response to [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70899051/15355839) by coding:

```
const property1 = object?.property1
```

rather than:

`const property1 = object.property1` or `const { property1 } = object`

This approach doesn't work when the object is an array of objects, for instance if I want to preempt a fatal error in react while my array is undefined, I can't use:

```
const property1 = array?[0]?.property1
```

since it is syntactically incorrect (should it be?), so I am using:

```
 `const property1 = array && array[0]?.property1`
```

Is that the correct way?

[Daniel Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3412322/daniel-beck) corrected an error in my original question, that is now fixed indicating that an alternative way to handle this situation would be:

```
const uid = array ? array[0].uid : undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't check it, since I was quoting from somebody else, I should have! I will edit it and change the quote to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.isArray()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method to determine whether the passed value is an `Array` or not.

**Working Demo :**

```js
let obj = {
    property1: 'alpha' 
};

const property1 = Array.isArray(obj) ? obj[0]?.property1 : obj.property1;

console.log(property1);
```